# Is there any free library to play various sound format in .NET?

Tags: .net, audio

I would like to play sound in my application, as far as I know, .net can only handle wav files by default. Is there any sound playing library which I can use? I know about bass but it is not free for commercial use. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/), its open source and will allow you to play and audio file that you have a codec for.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be toembed the Windows Media Player, [as is done here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Play_sound_in_VBnet_with.aspx). Is there a specific format you'd like to support?